# Not able to Assign LUIS subscription key to App - API V2.0

Tags: rest, api, azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have to assign the subscription key to luis app which i created on azure.

I am using LUIS Api V2.0 to ***Assign Subscription Key To App***.

I have used **Update application version external key** endpoint for it.
    https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/externalKeys

(API sample url)  https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c43/console

I have created the new LUIS subscription key from azure. However, I am not able to assign the subscription key to my app.

Below is my body request

```
{
    "type": "LanguageUnderstanding",
    "value": "ee29*******************717"
}
```

below is the response which i got.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Invalid external key type"
  }
}
```

I have modified the type variable in my request body like, Cognitive Service

- CognitiveService
- Cognitive Services
- CognitiveServices Language
- Understanding Intelligent Service
- LanguageUnderstandingIntelligentService
- LanguageUnderstanding
- Language Understanding

But, none of them seems working for me. I am getting the same error response every time.

---

Further, I have googled around and found that this is possible with LUIS Api V1.0 . So, I tried with **Assign Subscription Key To App**

( API sample url ) https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/580c6eea39e2bb161819981d/console

following is my endpoint https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/5b2556b8-f97d-4772-9bf0-4f576ec9fc59/subscription

Request body

```
08ebb******************e7142d3
```

Request Header

```
{ "Content-Type" : "text/plain", "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"as23d*******123d"}
```

Error Response

```
{
  "Message": "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."
}
```

I even tried with content-type:application/json. but , it too was not working.

So. I am not able to assign the subscription key by using either V1.0 or V2.0 LUIS api

Please guide me how assign newly created subscription key to luis with api.

I have also tried the following V2.0 endpoint requests, but they are deprecated now.
**Assign subscription key to version , Add external api key, Add subscription key**

Answer (score 2):

You can use a new endpoint which allows you to add keys programmatically - [endpoint](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32228e8473de116325515)

To use it you need:

1. Get an Azure Resource Manager token from this [link](https://resources.azure.com/api/token?plaintext=true). This token does expire so use it immediately. The request returns an Azure Resource Manager token. Or you can use Azure CLI:

   az account get-access-token --query accessToken -o tsv
2. Assign the token to the LUIS resource with the [endpoint](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32228e8473de116325515)

This POST API requires the following settings:

Header: Authorization - The value of Authorization is Bearer {token}. (Notice that the token value must be preceded by the word Bearer and a space.)

Header: Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key - Your authoring key.

Header: Content-type - application/json
Query string: appid - The LUIS app ID.

Body :

```
{"AzureSubscriptionId":"ddda2925-af7f-4b05-9ba1-2155c5fe8a8e",
"ResourceGroup": "resourcegroup-2",
"AccountName": "luis-uswest-S0-2"}
```

When this API is successful, it returns a 201 - created status.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-keys#assign-resource-without-luis-portal)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation which you are referring to is for the old version(v1). Assigning subscription key through Programmatic API has been **deprecated** as mentioned [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c42).

Azure Endpoint Keys are now automatically provided based on which Tenant ID and Subscription Name you select when choosing the key in your LUIS application’s **“Publish app”** page. Users are **no longer** required to copy "[Keys from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/azureibizasubscription)" and then manually add them to their LUIS accounts. The link I provided you earlier that leads to “[Manage your keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/manage-keys)” provides a walkthrough process of how to assign a key to your app.

If you have any other concerns for LUIS support, please contact luservice@microsoft.com.

Comment: Your reply is helpful. However, my requirement is to assign keys by using an API. And the way which you mentioned was by using LUIS portal. Can you share if you have any idea of assigning keys in Luis API V2.0

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have that feature through API for now. Will update if they implement in near future.

Comment: We also require this API method. I submitted a feature request here https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-luis/suggestions/33446179-assign-keys-to-an-app

Comment: Sure. We'd definitely consider this in future. Thanks for submitting your feature request.